# GetProcAddress doesn't return the real address for LoadLibraryA

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, dll, loadlibrary

```
DWORD dwLoadLibrary = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
```

When I go to the returned address in OllyDbg I can see that this address points to the code which jumps to the real address of LoadLibraryA. I want to get the real address of LoadLibraryA which doesn't change because kernel32.dll is loaded at the same location in every process and also I would like to know why GetProcAddress doesn't return the real address.

[image]

Comment: not use `(DWORD)` for *pointer* even if you decide coding only for 32-bit platform (what is strange). use `DWORD_PTR` instead or `void*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the "real" address of `kernel32.LoadLibraryA`, as `GetProcAddress()` returns the real address.  It is just that the implementation of `kernel32.LoadLibrayA` has moved from `kernel32.dll` to `kernelbase.dll`, and as a result `kernel32.LoadLibraryA` simply consists of a single instruction:

```
jmp dword ptr[kernelbase.LoadLibraryA]
```

If you look at more functions in `kernel32.dll`, many of them also have this same pattern:

```
kernel32.somefunc:
    jmp [kernelbase.somefunc]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the "real" address of `LoadLibraryA`. The jump instruction is there for tools to put an indirection there. They would swap the destination address of that jump with something else, pointing to the hook, and jump to the original location after executing the hook to actually execute the function.

Comment: Does it mean that the returned address from GetProcAddress for LoadLibraryA doesn't change in each process?

Comment: This is up to the dynamic linker, so yes, it can change.

Comment: no, this is not hook, and point of `LoadLibraryA` not changed

Answer (score 1):

How do you know it is not the real address of `LoadLibraryA`? Maybe try WinDbg instead?

On my Windows 8 system `GetProcAddress(x, "LoadLibraryA")` returns a function that begins with the normal `mov edi,edi` hotpatch reservation (and the rest of the function) but that does not mean that it can't start with a jump in other versions.